# Using Wildcard with `IN ('%')`?

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to modify the `('%')` to return a single row for the following query, i.e. while keeping the entire statement before it?

`select 1 FROM DUAL WHERE TRIM('asdfsdf') in ('%')`

Comment: What's the actual situation you need this for? Why are you trimming a string literal in the where clause? Does `WHERE TRIM('asdfsdf') in (TRIM('asdfsdf'))` do what you need? Why not if so?

Comment: In a function, given an optional list of values, I added a `where X IN (value1, value2, ...)` or `x LIKE '%'`. Thinking about your and Joishi's post, perhaps I shouldn't even add the `filter` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible to use the `LIKE` wildcard in an `IN` statement.  To achieve what you want to do, you need to take out all your `LIKE` wildcards and put them in a separate `OR` clause.

```
WHERE string_col IN ('string1', 'string2')
   OR string_col LIKE '%string3%'
   OR string_col LIKE '%string4%'
```

But this seems like a REALLY bad idea ... I think you should update your post to answer Martin's question (in the comment) to get a better solution for what you want to do.  (or ask a different question)

Comment: `But this seems like a REALLY bad idea ` Is that because it's better to simply exclude the `x LIKE '%'` filter?

Comment: Filtering based off of wildcards/regex tends to be fairly expensive task..  You're thinking of filtering on multiple possibilities of wildcards .. which makes me think that the query would end up being incredibly slow once the table reaches a certain size.